# Why isn't my hamburger icon working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNqgMo

Why is the top line not animating? Could someone tell me what's wrong in the code?

Thanks

```
#hamburger-icon.active .line-1 {
transform: translateY(25px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: translateY(25px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: translateY(25px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}
#hamburger-icon.active .line-2 {
opacity: 0;
}
#hamburger-icon.active .line-3 {
transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
```

Comment: What do you want the outcome to be?

Comment: I want the top line to do the same as the bottom line is doing . Rotating 45 degrees down

Comment: On line 38 you have a extra `}` When you delete it, magic happens

Answer (score 4):

Here you go :

[See this code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyWwpM)

```
#hamburger-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  height: 27px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;


}

#hamburger-icon .line {

  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: #c8c8c8;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;

 }

  #hamburger-icon .line.line-1 {
    top: 0px;
  }

  #hamburger-icon .line.line-2 {
    top: 7px;
  }

  #hamburger-icon .line.line-3 {
    top: 14px;
  }


#hamburger-icon.active .line-1 {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}
#hamburger-icon.active .line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
#hamburger-icon.active .line-3 {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

You add one bracket too much to your code so it wasn't working

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra bracket after

```
#hamburger-icon .line.line-3 {
    top: 14px;
}
```

just remove it and your code will work as intended

```
#hamburger-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  height: 27px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;


}

#hamburger-icon .line {

  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: #c8c8c8;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;

 }

  #hamburger-icon .line.line-1 {
    top: 0px;
  }

  #hamburger-icon .line.line-2 {
    top: 7px;
  }

  #hamburger-icon .line.line-3 {
    top: 14px;
  }



#hamburger-icon.active .line-1 {
  transform: translateY(25px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(25px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(25px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}
#hamburger-icon.active .line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
#hamburger-icon.active .line-3 {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
}
```